# Stacked Bar Graphs with ‘Nested Data’ for two Y-Axis Categories

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Re: Stacked Bar Graphs with ‘Nested Data’ for two Y-Axis Categories

Forgive me if I have a hard time articulating our need.  I have two data sets that have the following content:

1. Number of Placements by Employee By Month
2. Number of Placements by Project By Month

Thats means there are four dimensions at play:

1. The Month (the x-axis on both data set charts)
2. Number of Placements (the y-axis value on both charts)
3. The Employee (the y-axis category on chart 1)
4. The Project (the y-axis category on chart 2)

I want to see this data in one stacked bar chart where the months are on the x-axis, the placements are on the y-axis and then:

Option 1. The stacked bar chart shows the employee contribution to number of placements each month (regular stacked bar chart) and within the enployee section it ‘nests’ or shows the number of placements on projects they worked on.

Then the inverse:

Option 2.  The stacked bar chart shows the project contributions to number of placements each month (regular stacked bar chart) and within that section it ‘nests’ the employee contribution to the number of placements to that project.

Does this make sense?  It doesnt seem possible but you guys are basically miracle workers!  If anyone can help, even just tell me its impossible, that’d be great!

‘GLORY TO UKRAINE!! ‘

Comment: Stack is not a place to slip political, religious or personal views in. I'm neither agreeing nor disagreeing with your sentiment; if you'd have said something opposing at the bottom of your post, I'd be saying the same thing. Please remove the person and unrelated content from your post.

Comment: You've started your post saying that what you are trying to do is hard to even articulate. But then you went on to try to explain this difficult concept without showing us what you're working with. Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know your layout, data, data types, data locations; we don't know your field; we don't know your end goal. So what started out as already difficult for you to explain is "mud" for those of us out here who can't see what you are seeing. (You're basically asking us to "image" what you see.) Please share a link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Thanks for the recent edit, but It doesn't really help with understanding your data or your problem. You asked _does this make sense?_ and, maybe this is just me, have to reply "no". So that we can try to help you, would you please edit your question to include the following: 1) sample data for both scenarios; include this as a table or a spreadsheet - please do NOT provide via a screenshot. 2) graph(s) based on the same data that show what you are trying to achieve; you can draw these and include as screenshots; they are essential to understand your problem/goal.